# Why is the small white box near my fridge's compressor making an incessant clicking sound?

Tags: repair, appliances, refrigerator

I have a small Frigidaire (model FRT045GB) ~9 months old (but shockingly outside of warranty) which recently started clicking. Actually it almost sounds like a small water pump?

I have been able to determine that the noise is related to the fridge (not the freezer). When I turn the fridge temp down the noise will stop for a while, but start again when the cooling system starts up again.

It seems to be coming from this white box near the compressor. When I touch it I can feel the vibration. The white box has a recycle symbol and 'ABS' on the front. It also has Y-shaped notch in the screws which hold it on so taking it apart will be a pain.

Anyone know what this box is for, what would make that noise, or how I might fix it?

The fridge is still working, just making noise. maybe ~4 clicks/second? not too loud but I am sure it is not normal.

Comment: I don't think I can help with your question, but I do believe a photo of the "small white box" might help others give you a more exact answer.

Comment: Are you sure that model number is correct?

Comment: Basically nothing on this refrigerator is serviceable (other than the light bulb and leveling feet), so even if the part is bad you'll be hard pressed to find a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar odd sound from the back of our refrigerator.

There's a few different parts back there that can make noise: The compressor, condenser fans, and defrost timer.  Apparently the fans can be cleaned fairly easily, and the timer can be replaced if its electric motor starts making noise.

In my case, we called in an independent service technician (found via Service Magic).  He diagnosed the problem for us at no charge.  Unfortunately for us it was the compressor, and a new unit would cost almost as much as a new fridge, so we ended up getting a new fridge.

But in your case, maybe you're lucky and it's one of the other parts.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but I no longer possess the fridge so I cannot check. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Brand new fridge (Frigidaire). The same sound coming from a white box attached with ABS stamped on it. I unplugged the fridge and removed the box to examine the components. It appears to be a thermostat of some sort? It also has a little red adjustment screw in the center of the component. I am making my best guess and thinking that it regulates when the pump kicks on according to the ambient temperature?

Best guess 2, some sort of power regulator, maybe for different types of electricity? But the housing is cylindrical and the red dial is dead center leading me to believe that it is a coil inside. The dial is to tighten or loosen the spring to optimize efficiency for different climates or elevations?

Either way, I left the box off and plugged the fridge back in to see if it would keep making the sound. The sound stopped. This tells me that it is a poor design, allowing vibrations to be amplified by the housing. A little cardboard between the housing and the metal cylinder and the sound is gone forever. I do not recommend doing this unless you have some basic knowledge in electricity, and insurance on your house..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like the electric relay valve for the icemaker.  Do you have an icemaker, and if so is it hooked up?  If not, turn the icemaker off...